# откуда в woocommerce подгружаются ($current_min_price и $min_price) в price_filter.php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: код]

Так же, могу ли я добавить изменения content-widget-price-filter.php в function.php дочерней темы. Чтобы ничего не слетело при обновлении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В твоей дочерней теме должна быть папка **woocommerce**, куда ты можешь скопировать content-widget-price-filter.php

Вообще, все изменения в шаблонах вукоммерс можно делать скопировав из папки:

***\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\

в папку

***\wp-content\themes\you-theme\woocommerce\

Далее, если ты хочешь вмешаться в логику фильтры, есть фильтры, которые ты можешь найти например в файле

class-wc-widget-price-filter.php, который находится в папке

***\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\widgets\class-wc-widget-price-filter.php

Там смотришь требуемые тебе значения и выискиваешь apply_filters.
Если есть, то вешаешь в function.php совей темы обработчик фильтра и вуаля!